# How to include external JavaScript on my Moodle page?

Tags: javascript, php, moodle

In Moodle, while we use `$PAGE->requires->js_init_call()` to include a JS function defined in our plugin's `module.js` file, **how can I include *external Javascript resources***, which we normally include in the `<head>` tags like:

```
<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

<title>mypage</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.5.0/build/yahoo-dom-event/yahoo-dom-event.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.5.0/build/element/element-beta-min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.5.0/build/connection/connection-min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.5.0/build/tabview/tabview-min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: Just put it into the template?

Comment: Where do you want add your external js in a module or theme?

Comment: @SumanBogati I want to display it on the `attempt_form` in the page where the student attempts a question in a quiz. It is the `attempt.php` file in the `quiz` module. Actually to render the output, `attempt_page()` function of the quiz `renderer` is called from `attempt.php`. This method calls the `attempt_form` method. This is exactly where I need to load the JS. It is actually a TabView (from YUI JS library) which  I want to display. I want to use [this code](http://css-tricks.com/simple-tabbed-box/), but I do not know where to put different bits of it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use following code to include javascript file in your code:

```
$PAGE->requires->js() 

E.g

$PAGE->requires->js( new moodle_url($CFG->wwwroot . '/local/my_localplugin/myjavascript.js'));
```

Comment: This is not the answer to this question.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following code to include a javascript file in your code inside the :

```
$PAGE->requires->js('/mod/namemodule/socket.io.js',true);
```

In this way, the file is loaded `socket.io.js` within the `<head> </head>`

Comment: In Moodle 2.0 used $PAGE->requires->js().

Make $PAGE available to your code by doing:

require_once($CFG->libdir . '/pagelib.php');
global $PAGE;

Add our code:

$PAGE->requires->js( new moodle_url($CFG->wwwroot . '/mod/mymod/script.js') );

It is required to put moodle_url() around your path!