# Moodle, how to add a custom jQuery script to exercute on all pages

Tags: javascript, php, content-management-system, moodle

I am new to moodle. I have a requirement to run a js every time a user clicks on a download file or watch a video.
I don't know where or how to add these files.

I have seen how $page is used.

But is there a global location, like the, master page in .net?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to include external JavaScript on my Moodle page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25219176/how-to-include-external-javascript-on-my-moodle-page)

Comment: Its a bit different, I want a global page load.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a new js file in your Moodle theme folder.

Path to create new js file

```
theme->your_theme_folder->javascript-> create new js file here.
```

Now include your js file in your_theme_folder->config.php like below code

```
$THEME->javascripts_footer = array('modernizr');
```

Then you have to purge all cache in Moodle by going to

```
Site Administration->Development->Purge all caches
```

That's it your js code will work on all page